# Unable to apply Bootstrap5 sticky footer template in react js app

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to apply the following template to my react.js app: [Sticky footer Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sticky-footer/)

The markup in my app looks like: [image]

Except for the div with "root" id is extra otherwise I am exactly imitating the bootstrap 5 example given above. However, the footer is not sticking to the bottom.

Looks like this: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want the footer be in the bottom of your browser view (cause in this case is working) ? or in the bottom of your current App ?

Comment: Pardon me. I want the exact behaviour as in the bootstrap 5 sticky footer template where the footer is attached to the bottom of the page. Footer in my app is not at the bottom but in the middle of the page when there is no content in the app view.

Comment: Can you post the code snipet to see what is going wrong ?

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the div with id `root` from *index.html*.

Changed the *index.js* to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.body
);
```